# Computed property in struct associated enum

Tags: swift, enums

I'm trying to build a relationship between an enum and struct.  I would like to have a computed property in a struct that returns for each element of an enum.  However, the struct doesn't have an instance of this enum - it's more of a static implementation.  I'm looking for suggestions on syntax to make this code work right - or perhaps a better way of representing my types.  Here is example code:

```
enum ScaleDegree: Int {
    case tonic
    case supertonic
    // there's more...
}

struct Scale {
    // among other things, 
    // returns scale notes for the diatonic chords associated with the ScaleDegree
    var triad: [Int] {
        switch ScaleDegree {
        case .tonic: return [1, 3, 5]
        case .supertonic: return [2, 4, 6]
        }
    }
}
```

Of course the above doesn't compile.  However, it's a good example of what I'm trying to do.  In this example, I don't want an instance of ScaleDegree in Scale, but I do want Scale to be able to provide a result for every ScaleDegree.  Suggestions on an elegant way to do this?

Comment: A computed property or function can only return one thing (ok it might be made up of multiple items like a tuple)  so you can't do what you want as such because what is triad going to return.  Do you want triad to return every possible combination for the enum in which case it will need to return an array or dictionary of [Int]

Answer (score 1):

You can make `triad` part of the enum itself:

```
enum ScaleDegree: Int {
    case tonic
    case supertonic

    var triad: [Int] {
        switch self {
        case .tonic:
            return [1,3,5]
        case .supertonic:
            return [2,4,6]
        }
    }
}
```

Or turn it into a function in the struct:

```
struct Scale {
    func triad (degree: ScaleDegree) -> [Int] {
        switch degree {
        case .tonic: return [1, 3, 5]
        case .supertonic: return [2, 4, 6]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  What triad returns really is Scale oriented, so I do want to keep it in the Scale definition.  What I really want to do is, for example, initialize another struct, say a Chord, with scale.triad.tonic which is different syntax than calling a func.